Why are Image Fields not being created in Django Factory Boy?
I tried to follow the standard recipe for image fields in django factory boy:
class ConfigurationSingletonFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Configuration
        django_get_or_create = ("id",)

    id = 1

    custom_theme = ImageField(color="blue", width=200, height=200)



class GeneralConfiguration(SingletonModel):
    custom_theme = PrivateMediaImageField("Custom background", upload_to="themes", blank=True)

I tried to test it with the following code snippet:
def test_config(self):
    conf = GeneralConfigurationSingletonFactory(
        custom_theme__name="image.png"
    )
    print(conf.custom_theme.width)
    self.assertEqual(conf.custom_theme.width, 200)

On doing so, I encounter the following error:
ValueError: The 'custom_theme' attribute has no file associated with it.
I thought I did exactly what the documentation says. What am I misunderstanding?
